# Signedness of enum in C/C99/C++/C++x/GNU C/GNU C99

Tags: c++, c, enums, c99, signed

Is the `enum` type signed or unsigned? Does the signedness of enums differ between: C/C99/ANSI C/C++/C++x/GNU C/ GNU C99?

Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

An enum is guaranteed to be represented by an integer, but the actual type (and its signedness) is implementation-dependent.

You can force an enumeration to be represented by a signed type by giving one of the enumerators a negative value:

```
enum SignedEnum { a = -1 };
```

In C++0x, the underlying type of an enumeration can be explicitly specified:

```
enum ShortEnum : short { a };
```

(C++0x also adds support for scoped enumerations)

For completeness, I'll add that in *The C Programming Language, 2nd ed.*, enumerators are specified as having type `int` (p. 215).  K&R is not the C standard, so that's not normative for ISO C compilers, but it does predate the ISO C standard, so it's at least interesting from a historical standpoint.

Comment: What signedness is actually used by gcc?

Comment: @osgx:  I would guess that it would depend on the number of enumerators and the range of their values.  I really don't know.

Comment: The C standard also specifies that each *enumeration constant* has type `int`. Howeve, the term “enumeration constant” refers to the value constants declared inside the `enum { }` block. A variable with an `enum` type may have any integer type in C, e.g. it might be a shorter type than `int` if one can represent all the values. (GCC, for example, has an option `-fshort-enums` for doing precisely this.)

Comment: The term "enumerator" is commonly understood as the enumeration constant, and AFAIK inside the `enum{}` they never have a type smaller than `int` because the compiler doesn't know yet what values will follow.

Comment: @MSalters @Arkku:  That's true; in C, enumeration constants are always of type `int`.  In C++, they are of the same type as their initializer, so they could be of any integral type.

Comment: @osgx GCC decides at compile time what signedness to apply to an `enum`.  I have an enumerator with values from zero upwards and within a function check that the values of that enumerator are never less than zero (it is used as an array index).  GCC gives me an warning `avServerApi.c:23: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false`  If I put a dummy `-1` in the `enum` then the warning goes away as the enumerator is then signed.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question... but I've just found out this:

```
typedef unsigned ENUMNAME;  // this makes it unsigned in MSVC C 2015
typedef enum {v0, v1, v2, v3} ENUMNAME;
```

You can use it as an 2-bit unsigned index, for example:

```
typedef struct {
  ENUMNAME i:2;
} STRUCTNAME;
```

Tried it in GCC ARM - doesn't work.
Also, WinDbg shows STRUCTNAME.i as a **number**, not as v0-v3.

Comment: Doesn't that code redefine type `ENUMNAME`?