# negative integer implicitly converted to unsigned type

Tags: c, gcc, enums, bit-fields

How would one set/unset enum value for something like the following. Using gcc, I get this annoying warning:

```
test.c:37: warning: negative integer implicitly converted to unsigned type
test.c:39: warning: negative integer implicitly converted to unsigned type
test.c:41: warning: negative integer implicitly converted to unsigned type
test.c:43: warning: negative integer implicitly converted to unsigned type
```

code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef enum {
 ONE = 0x1,
 TWO = 0x2,
 THREE = 0x4,
 FOUR = 0x8,
} options;

static const char *byte_to_binary (int x)
{
  int z;
  static char b[9];
  b[0] = '\0';

  for (z = 256; z > 0; z >>= 1)
    {
    strcat(b, ((x & z) == z) ? "1" : "0");
    }

  return b;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  options o = 0;
  printf( "%s\n", byte_to_binary(o));
  o |= ONE;
  printf( "%s\n", byte_to_binary(o));
  o |= TWO;
  printf( "%s\n", byte_to_binary(o));
  o |= THREE;
  printf( "%s\n", byte_to_binary(o));
  o |= FOUR;
  printf( "%s\n", byte_to_binary(o));
  o &= ~FOUR;
  printf( "%s\n", byte_to_binary(o));
  o &= ~THREE;
  printf( "%s\n", byte_to_binary(o));
  o &= ~TWO;
  printf( "%s\n", byte_to_binary(o));
  o &= ~ONE;
  printf( "%s\n", byte_to_binary(o));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This might be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579230/signedness-of-enum-in-c-c99-c-cx-gnu-c-gnu-c99

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your enum does not contain any negative integer constants, I guess GCC has given `unsigned` int type to your enums. Now the expressions like

```
o &= ~FOUR
```

are equivalent to

```
o = o & ~FOUR
```

On the RHS, `o` is unsigned int and `~FOUR` is signed int and by type conversion rules, signed int will be converted to unsigned int. Also `~FOUR` is a negative number and hence you get a warning for implicit conversion of a negative number to unsigned type.

If you are sure of your logic, you need not worry about the warnings or you can convert your enum to signed by having a dummy `enum` which equals to a negative number.

Something like

```
typedef enum {
 DUMMY =-1,
 ONE = 0x1,
 TWO = 0x2,
 THREE = 0x4,
 FOUR = 0x8,
} options;
```

Also, your code has run-time [buffer overflow problems](http://ideone.com/OtJnS). In function `byte_to_binary` you are checking for 9 bits, but your buffer is also 9 bytes. It has to be 10 bytes, one for the terminating null. Make it `static char b[10];` and everything [works fine](http://ideone.com/J1PE7)