# Why does libclang's clang_getEnumDeclIntegerType return different results on Linux and Windows?

Tags: c, libclang

Consider this simple C file, `file.c`:

```
enum X {
    A,
    B
}
```

Let's detect the underlying type of the enum using `libclang`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <clang-c/Index.h>

enum CXChildVisitResult visitor(CXCursor cursor, CXCursor parent, CXClientData client_data)
{
    if (clang_getCursorKind(cursor) == CXCursor_EnumDecl) {
            enum CXTypeKind kind = clang_getEnumDeclIntegerType(cursor).kind;
            printf("Type: %s\n", clang_getCString(clang_getTypeKindSpelling(kind)));
    }

    return CXChildVisit_Recurse;
}

int main()
{
    CXIndex index = clang_createIndex(0, 0);
    CXTranslationUnit unit = clang_parseTranslationUnit(index, "file.c", NULL, 0, NULL, 0, CXTranslationUnit_None);
    CXCursor cursor = clang_getTranslationUnitCursor(unit);
    clang_visitChildren(cursor, visitor, NULL);
}
```

This prints `Int` on Windows (Win10, VS 2015 toolkit, pre-compiled clang 6.0) and `Uint` on Linux (Ubuntu Xenial on the Linux subsystem for Windows, clang 6.0 packages).

Why is that? Is there a way to make the output identical on different platforms?

Comment: Use scoped enums to specify the underlying type.

Comment: There's no cross-platform guarantee about the size or signedness of an enum type. Differences between platforms probably come down to arbitrary choices made decades ago, with backward compatibility maintained all the way to the present. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579230/signedness-of-enum-in-c-c99-c-cx-gnu-c-gnu-c99

Comment: the only requirement for the type is that it can hold all values defined in the enum. if you want to make it cross-platform you need to specifie the type and set values to all of fields