# left shift count >= width of type in C macro

Tags: c, gcc, macros, stm32

I have written a C Macro to set/unset Bits in a uint32 variable. Here are the definitions of the macros:

```
extern uint32_t error_field, error_field2;
    #define SET_ERROR_BIT(x) do{\
                                if(x < 0 || x >63){\
                                    break;\
                                }\
                                if(((uint32_t)x)<32U){\
                                    (error_field |= ((uint32_t)1U << ((uint32_t)x)));\
                                    break;\
                                } else if(((uint32_t)x)<64U){\
                                    (error_field2 |= ((uint32_t)1U<<(((uint32_t)x)-32U)));\
                                }\
                            }while(0)

    #define RESET_ERROR_BIT(x) do{\
                                if(((uint32_t)x)<32U){\
                                    (error_field &= ~((uint32_t)1U<<((uint32_t)x)));\
                                    break;\
                                } else if(((uint32_t)x) < 64U){\
                                    (error_field2 &= ~((uint32_t)1U<<(((uint32_t)x)-32U)));\
                                }\
                             } while(0)
```

I am passing a field of an enumeration, that looks like this:

```
enum error_bits {
    error_chamber01_data = 0,
    error_port21_data,
    error_port22_data,
    error_port23_data,
    error_port24_data,
/*this goes on until 47*/
};
```

This warning is produced:

> left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]

I am calling the Macros like this:

```
USART2->CR1 |= USART_CR1_RXNEIE;
SET_ERROR_BIT(error_usart2);
/*error_usart2 is 47 in the enum*/
return -1;
```

I get this warning with every macro, even with those where the left shift count is < 31.

If I use the definition of the macro without the macro, it produces no warning. The behaviour is the same with a 64 bit variable. I am programming a STM32F7 with AC6 STM32 MCU GCC compiler.
I can't figure out why this happens. Can anyone help me?

Comment: show where the macro is called also

Comment: I have edited the post.

Comment: This (and I really *don't* mean to cause offence here) truly hideous beast is a classic example of why macros are a bad idea for anything other than simple true/false things in modern C compilers. You could write something *far* more readable with a function that generally has *little* performance impact, if any. I always try to optimise for readabilty first :-)

Comment: I already thought of writing a function for this, but i want to figure out why the warning is produced

Comment: does the enum contain some negative value which may change the next enum values?

Comment: Vincent, you may also want to know why your car gears always crunch and don't last very long. Or you could take the advice of a mechanic and start using the clutch :-)

Comment: In the macros, you distinguish two cases, which, on their own, are okay. The warning comes from the branch that isn't executed, where the shift is out of range. (Apparently these disgnostics are issued before the dead branch is eliminated.)

Comment: Yes, probably it is actually better to write a function for it. @LoPiTaL no, there are no negativ numbers in the enumeration

Comment: @MOehm but why is no warning generated if i use the definition without macro? Even if use value > 32?

Comment: Hmm. I get them with the expanded version, too, and that's how I found out where exactly the warnig was issued. I don't get them when I use a variable instead of an enumerated value or a number literal.

Comment: @When i tested it without the macro, i used a uint32_t as 'x'. I will test it using the enumeration

Comment: Oh i see my fault, thank you! I will use a function for this from now on.

Comment: Try to use something like this: `#define SET_ERROR_BIT(x) (
    ((x)>63)?(x)=(x):((x)<32)?
    (err1 |= (1U<<(x))):
    (err2 |= (1U<<((x)-32)))
    )` where x shall be an unsigned int.

Comment: VincentFartmann, re: [no, there are no negativ numbers in the enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53479744/left-shift-count-width-of-type-in-c-macro#comment93829633_53479744) is not sufficient to prevent negative values passed to your macro as with unexpected code `SET_ERROR_BIT(error_chamber01_data - error_port21_data)`. [Signedness of enum in C/C99/C++/C++x/GNU C/GNU C99](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2579230/2410359).  The compiler may consider negative values a possibility.

Comment: I thought it will always be positive, cause the enums are ascending and because the number 1 to 47 have the same represantation in signed and unsigned. so all values should be positive unless i explicitly specify it or an overflow occurs? Of course your code example would have unexpacted behavior, but why should i do this: `SET_ERROR_BIT(error_chamber01_data - error_port21_data);` ?

Answer (score 2):

Probably a problem with the compiler not being able to diagnose correctly, as stated by M Oehm. A workaround could be, instead of using the minus operation, use the remainder operation:

```
#define _SET_BIT(x, bit) (x) |= 1U<<((bit) % 32U)
#define SET_BIT(x, bit) _SET_BIT(x, (uint32_t)(bit))
#define _SET_ERROR_BIT(x) do{\
                            if((x)<32U){\
                                SET_BIT(error_field, x);\
                            } else if((x)<64U){\
                                SET_BIT(error_field2, x);\
                            }\
                        }while(0)
#define SET_ERROR_BIT(x) _SET_ERROR_BIT((uint32_t)(x))
```

This way the compiler is finally smart enough to know that the value of `x` will never exceed 32.

The call to the "_" macro is used in order to force `x` to always be an uint32_t, inconditionally of the macro call, avoiding the UB of a call with a negative value of `x`.

Tested in [coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7cc70184623aa311)

Comment: This works fine for numbers <32. For numbers >=32 it produces the same warning: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d79a452e4a6efda

Comment: yes, because the other branch needs also the modulus operation, I update the link

Comment: I have also simplified the macro, removing unnecessary castings and breaks

Comment: I figured out the fault, see the last comment. Thank you!

Comment: It can be further improved as `SET_ERROR_BIT(x) do{ if((x)<32U){ SET_BIT(error_field); } else { SET_BIT(error_field2);} }` where `SET_BIT` is `SET_BIT(field) ( (field) |= 1U <<  ((x)%32U) )`.

Comment: @Lundin code modified, adapted from yours. Your code is lacking the pass of both, the variable and bit index to `SET_BIT`

Comment: `%` is not the mod operator.  It is the remainder operator.  `(bit) % 32U` will never exceed 32 is true, yet with pathological input  `SET_ERROR_BIT(-1LL)`, code is UB as `-1LL % 32U` is less than 0 for the shift.  OP code tested `x` range and robustly does not have this vulnerability, unlike this code.   OP's `if(x < 0 || x >63){` was a good idea to not set an error bit when out of range.

Comment: @chux Updated the remainder operator. Modified also to avoid the UB and the duplicate starting `if` of the OP

Comment: Good update to prevent UB.  Note your answer is functionally different than OP's with `x < 0` with pathological input `SET_ERROR_BIT(-1LL)`  (OP's code sets nothing in that case).  Perhaps `if ((x) < 0) { ; } else if((x)<32){\
                                SET_BIT(error_field, x);\
                            } else if((x)<64){\
                                SET_BIT(error_field2, x);\
                            }`?

Comment: @chux with my code nothing is set either. If `-1LL` is passed, the explicit conversion to `uint32_t` made by the call to the "_" macro will result in `0xFFFFFFFF` as `uint32_t`, which is a positive number larger than 64, so both `if`s will be skipped.

Comment: Yes, with -1LL that is true, did not see that. Still hole remains, but in a new, and less likely, place such as SET_ERROR_BIT(-0x100000000) as the `(uint32_t)` cast simply wraps the negative values and then some  will end up as 0-63.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the thread I wanted to indicate a nice (and perhaps cleaner) way to set, reset and toggle the status of a bit in the case of the two unsigned integers as in thread. This code should be OT because uses x that shall be an `unsigned int` (or an `int`) and not a `enum` value.

I've written the line of code at the end of this answer.

The code receives as input a number of parameter couples. Each couple of parameter is a letter and a number. The letter may be:

- S to set a bit
- R to reset a bit
- T to toggle a bit

The number has to be a bit value from 0 to 63. The macros in the code discard each number greater than 63 and nothing is modified into the variables. The negative values haven't been evalued because we suppose a bit value is an unsigned value.

For Example (if we name the program bitman):

Executing: bitman S 0 S 1 T 7 S 64 T 7 S 2 T 80 R 1 S 63 S 32 R 63 T 62

The output will be:

S  0 00000000-00000001
S  1 00000000-00000003
T  7 00000000-00000083
S 64 00000000-00000083
T  7 00000000-00000003
S  2 00000000-00000007
T 80 00000000-00000007
R  1 00000000-00000005
S 63 80000000-00000005
S 32 80000001-00000005
R 63 00000001-00000005
T 62 40000001-00000005

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

static uint32_t err1 = 0;
static uint32_t err2 = 0;

#define SET_ERROR_BIT(x) (\
    ((unsigned)(x)>63)?err1=err1:((x)<32)?\
    (err1 |= (1U<<(x))):\
    (err2 |= (1U<<((x)-32)))\
    )

#define RESET_ERROR_BIT(x) (\
    ((unsigned)(x)>63)?err1=err1:((x)<32)?\
    (err1 &= ~(1U<<(x))):\
    (err2 &= ~(1U<<((x)-32)))\
    )

#define TOGGLE_ERROR_BIT(x) (\
    ((unsigned)(x)>63)?err1=err1:((x)<32)?\
    (err1 ^= (1U<<(x))):\
    (err2 ^= (1U<<((x)-32)))\
    )

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    unsigned int x;

    for(i=1;i<argc;i+=2) {
        x=strtoul(argv[i+1],NULL,0);

        switch (argv[i][0]) {
        case 'S':
            SET_ERROR_BIT(x);
            break;
        case 'T':
            TOGGLE_ERROR_BIT(x);
            break;
        case 'R':
            RESET_ERROR_BIT(x);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        printf("%c %2d %08X-%08X\n",argv[i][0], x, err2, err1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The macros are splitted in more then one line, but they are each a one-line code.

The code main has no error control then if the parameters are not correctly specified the program might be undefined behaviour.

Comment: OP's code handled `x < 0`.  This answer, like [first one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53480064/2410359), has vulnerability when `x < 0`.

Comment: It's not a vulnerability to avoid the x<0 control, because the input variable should be considered an unsigned at compilation time. If you use an int the code will be compiled with error. If you force the variable at a negative value the code will consider the value as a number greater or equal to 0, so it is sufficient to consider the control on greater than 63.

Comment: Disagree with "because the input variable should be considered an unsigned at compilation time".  Enumerated values are not certainly _unsigned_ [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579230/signedness-of-enum-in-c-c99-c-cx-gnu-c-gnu-c99) and OP wisely wants to prevent possibility  with `if(x < 0`

Comment: In the code I've implemented the variable x is an unsigned. May be I'm OT.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

> In the macros, you distinguish two cases, which, on their own, are okay. The warning comes from the branch that isn't executed, where the shift is out of range. (Apparently these diagnostics are issued before the dead branch is eliminated.) 
>     [@M Oehm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53480064/2410359)

**Solution**

Insure shifts are in range 0-31 in both paths regardless of the `x` value *and* type of `x`.

`x & 31` is a stronger insurance than `x%32` or `x%32u`.  `%` can result in negative remainders when `x < 0` and with a wide enough type.

```
   #define SET_ERROR_BIT(x) do{\
                                if((x) < 0 || (x) >63){\
                                    break;\
                                }\
                                if(((uint32_t)x)<32U){\
                                    (error_field |= ((uint32_t)1U << ( (x)&31 )));\
                                    break;\
                                } else if(((uint32_t)x)<64U){\
                                    (error_field2 |= ((uint32_t)1U<<( (x)&31 )));\
                                }\
                            }while(0)
```

---

As a general rule: good to use `()` around each usage of `x`.