# C (gnu11) enum variable can't compare to int?

Tags: c, enums, enumeration

This seems really weird to me, and I've never seen any discussion of it in resources about C enums. The variable `a` is of type `enum Direction`, and it can be -1, but `a<0` will be false. What am I missing about enums?

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum Direction {N,W,S,E};

int main()
{
    enum Direction a = N;
    printf("a is %d\n", a);
    a--;
    printf("now a is %d\n", a);
    printf("but (a<0) is %d\n\n", (a<0));
    
    int b = N;
    printf("b is %d\n", b);
    b--;
    printf("now b is %d\n", b);
    printf("and (b<0) is %d\n", (b<0));
 
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
a is 0
now a is -1
but (a<0) is 0

b is 0
now b is -1
and (b<0) is 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Signedness of enum in C/C99/C++/C++x/GNU C/GNU C99](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579230/signedness-of-enum-in-c-c99-c-cx-gnu-c-gnu-c99)

Comment: `printf("Direction is %s\n", _Generic((enum Direction)0, int: "int", unsigned: "unsigned"));` (According to <https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit-fields-implementation.html>, `enum Direction` will alway be some unsigned type since there are no negative enumarators)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying type of an enum is an implementation-defined integer type that can represent all items of the enum. Here, it could be `char`, `int`, `unsigned int` (possibly others).

Your implementation apparently chose to use `unsigned int` ; it's consistent with the comparison to 0 (can't be negative), and you only have it printed as `-1` because in 2-complement, -1 has the same representation as "largest unsigned of the same width" (which is the value you have, because unsigned 0 minus 1 will wrap to the largest value).

It only prints as `-1` because of the `%d` format of printf, which converts it back to signed. But because it's unsigned, you should have used `%u`.

When you convert it to a signed integer by creating an int var, you have an actual int, so it behaves correctly (printed as `-1` by the `%d` format of printf).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what integer type is selected by the compiler to be compatible with the enumeration type. The compiler can select an unsigned integer type.

In this statement

```
printf("now a is %d\n", a);
```

you are using the conversion specifier `%d` designed for signed integer types though the enumeration can be compatible with an unsigned integer type and if you will use the conversion specifier `%u` you will get another result.

If for example you will declare an enumeration constant as having a negative value then the compiler will select a signed integer type as compatible with the enumeration.

Here are two demonstrative programs that show the difference

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    enum Direction {N,W,S,E};
    
    enum Direction a = N;
    
    --a;
    
    printf( "a < 0 is %d\n", a < 0 );
}
```

The output of this program is

```
a < 0 is 0
```

The compiler selected an unsigned integer type as the compatible integer type.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    enum Direction {N = -1, W,S,E};
    
    enum Direction a = W; // W is equal to 0
    
    --a;
    
    printf( "a < 0 is %d\n", a < 0 );
}
```

The output of this program is

```
a < 0 is 1
```

because the compiler selected a signed integer type as the compatible integer type.

Form the C Standard (6.7.2.2 Enumeration specifiers)

> 4 Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a signed integer
> type, or **an unsigned integer type**. The choice of type is
> implementation-defined,128) but shall be capable of representing the
> values of all the members of the enumeration. T

That is there is a difference between an enumeration type and an enumeration constant. Enumeration constants always have the type `int`. But enumeration types are compatible with integer types (signed or unsigned) selected by the compiler.

Compare the two calls of `printf` in this demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    enum Direction {N,W,S,E};
    
    enum Direction a = N;
    
    printf( "a - 1 < 0 is %d\n", a - 1 < 0 );
    printf( "N - 1 < 0 is %d\n", N - 1 < 0 );
}
```

where the program output is

```
a - 1 < 0 is 0
N - 1 < 0 is 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The pitfall is your format specifier when printing `a`. The format specifier `%d` lets `printf` interpret `a` as a signed integer, no matter what data type it actually is. But actually, it is an unsigned integer, and `a--` resulted in an overflow, i.e. `a == 4294967295`. Hence `a < 0` is `false`. When interpreting this value as a signed integer, it is -1. Try using `%u` as format specifier when printing `a` and you will see the real value of `a`.